# RoR - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /tour/show & Couldn't find Tour with Couldn't find Tour with 'id'=create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise

** Updated to match resent comment **
- new issue is flagged with couldnt find id=create 
- the framework is not creating any tours with specific id.

This issue has been troubling for some time and decided to start from scratch again to see if I missed anything. I am new to the RoR framework and it has been a great learning curve already.

**Project:** Tour website which allows host to post tours
**Aim:** To assign 'tours' to a host (which is using the Devise Gem)
**Current issue:** Am not able to assign id's to a create tour and not be able to see any tours being saved or created.

Attached are my file snapshots which have been updated as per previous user answer:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :host
  # devise_for :hosts

  resources :host, only: [:show]
  resources :tour

  #Root
  root 'static_pages#home'

  #Tour
  get 'tour/index'
  get 'tour/new'
  get 'tour/create'
  #get 'tours/:id'
  patch 'tour/update'
  get 'tour/show'
  get 'tour/edit'
  get 'tour/delete'
  get 'tour/update'

  #Static Pages 

  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
```

**Rake routes**

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
        new_host_session GET    /host/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            host_session POST   /host/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_host_session DELETE /host/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           host_password POST   /host/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_host_password GET    /host/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_host_password GET    /host/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /host/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /host/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_host_registration GET    /host/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       host_registration POST   /host(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_host_registration GET    /host/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_host_registration GET    /host/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /host(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /host(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /host(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    host GET    /host/:id(.:format)           host#show
              tour_index GET    /tour(.:format)               tour#index
                         POST   /tour(.:format)               tour#create
                new_tour GET    /tour/new(.:format)           tour#new
               edit_tour GET    /tour/:id/edit(.:format)      tour#edit
                    tour GET    /tour/:id(.:format)           tour#show
                         PATCH  /tour/:id(.:format)           tour#update
                         PUT    /tour/:id(.:format)           tour#update
                         DELETE /tour/:id(.:format)           tour#destroy
                    root GET    /                             static_pages#home
                         GET    /tour/index(.:format)         tour#index
                tour_new GET    /tour/new(.:format)           tour#new
             tour_create GET    /tour/create(.:format)        tour#create
             tour_update PATCH  /tour/update(.:format)        tour#update
               tour_show GET    /tour/show(.:format)          tour#show
               tour_edit GET    /tour/edit(.:format)          tour#edit
             tour_delete GET    /tour/delete(.:format)        tour#delete
                         GET    /tour/update(.:format)        tour#update
                   about GET    /about(.:format)              static_pages#about
                 contact GET    /contact(.:format)            static_pages#contact
```

**tour_controller.rb**

This is where I am getting the main problem with the def show or create id

```
       class TourController < ApplicationController
   #before_action :set_tour, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :create]
   before_action :authenticate_host!, except: [:create]
   before_action :host_session

   def index
        @tours = Tour.all
   end

   def show
        @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
   end

   def new
        @tour = Tour.new
   end

    def create
     @tour = Tour.new(tour_params)
     @tour.host = current_host
     @tour.save
    end

   def edit
        @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
        @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])

   if @tour.update_attributes(tour_param)
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @tour
   else
      render :action => 'edit'
   end
   end

   def delete
          Tour.find(params[:id]).destroy
   redirect_to :action => 'index'
   end

   def set_tour
      @tour = Tour.find_by_id(params[:id])
   end

private

   def tour_params
      #params.require(:tour_details).permit(:host_id) if params[:tour_details]
      params.require(:tour).permit(:host_id) if params[:tour]
   end
end
```

**_form.html erb**

Form being used for creating the tours, although in my database migration I am using a string field for the title - but RoR throws out this message when I use the f.string   ... so I always change it back to f.text_field

undefined method `string' for #
Did you mean?  String

```
 <h1>Add new tour</h1>

<%= form_for @tour do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description%>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Create" %>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'index'} %>
```

**show.html.erb**

This is my basic setup now but need to move it on when I can get the ID working with the tours.

```
<h1>show tour details</h1>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <h4><%= @tour.title %></h4>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Back' %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160711094000) do

  create_table "hosts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "hosts", ["email"], name: "index_hosts_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "hosts", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_hosts_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "tours", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.float    "price"
    t.integer  "tour_id"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.integer  "host_id"
  end

end
```

**New Error at /tour/create**

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /tour/create
Couldn't find Tour with 'id'=create

*snapshot from tour_controller which is highlighted from better errors*

def show
        @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])

{"controller"=>"tour", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"create"}

Instance variables - @_routes   nil

So to some up the basics of it.
- Host signs in (which is working with devise and provide as host.id)
- Create a tour (basic for now with only a title and description)
- The tour is assigned a unique id under the current host id.
- To create a tour with unique id

Answer (score 0):

In your route file you are manually creating routes. Instead use Rails default helpers. So in your route file you can use

```
resources :tours
```

It will automatically add the necessary CRUD routes for you. Then create a partial of your form and pass the instance variable in it. It will work for both updations and creations. Your form header would be

```
<%= form_for tour do |f| %>
```

You can call the form partial as

```
<%= render partial: 'form_partial_name' , locals: { tour: @tour } %>
```

For handling hosts just make an association of Host and Tour.
In tour.rb

```
belongs_to :host
```

In host.rb

```
has_many :hosts
```

Then in the create action you can do it as

```
def create
 @tour = Tour.new(tour_params)
 @tour.user = current_host
 @tour.save
end
```

With the associations intact you can now find out tours against hosts and host against tour.

```
@tour.host
@host.tours
```

Since you are setting the instance var inside each method, so there is no need to add this before_action filter

```
before_action :set_tour, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :create]
```

Comment: Thanks for getting bak to me regarding this.. I have implemented your changes although I don't understand the 'render partial' bit.
When I insert the partial code into the form - it brings up a new error '''' ActionView::MissingTemplate at /tour/new'''

Comment: Partials are used to DRY up your view. You are facing the error because your partial is missing. The name of the partial always starts with an underscore '_'. In your case, the name of your partial would be '_form_partial_name.html.erb'. For more information regarding partials and layouts Please follow this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
Thanks